# ASP.NET MVC built-in support for DropDownList editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to say my view model property should be rendered as `DropDownList` (so that I can specify `DropDownList` items)?

I have found a lot of custom implementations but I guess there should be a built-in way to implement such a basic thing.

**Update.** I am rendering my model by `Html.EditorForModel` method, I don't want to use methods like `Html.DropDownListFor`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no built-in template which renders a dropdown list, except for the `Nullable<bool>` type which renders a `Not Set`, `Yes`, `No` dropdown but I assume that's not what you are asking about.

So let's build one. As always we start by defining the view model that will represent a dropdown containing 2 properties (one for the selected value and one for the available values):

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public string SelectedId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

then we could have a standard view model with this property:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ItemViewModel Item { get; set; }
}
```

then a controller that will fill the view model:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Item = new ItemViewModel
            {
                SelectedId = "2",
                Items = new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
                    new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
                }
            }
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and a corresponding view (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
}
```

Now all that's left is to define a custom editor template for the `DropDownViewModel` type (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DropDownViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model DropDownViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.SelectedId, 
    new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedId)
)
```

and override the default template for the Object type in order to allow *Deep Dive* as Brad Wilson explains in [`his blog post`](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html). Otherwise by default ASP.NET MVC won't recurse into complex subtypes for your templates. So we override `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Object.cshtml`:

```
@foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) 
{
    if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) 
    {
        @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
    } 
    else 
    { 
        <div class="editor-label">
            @(prop.IsRequired ? "*" : "")
            @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)
            @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName, "*")
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: what is DropDownViewModel in the controller, is it ItemViewModel ?

Comment: This is not displaying dropdown for me. it is playing is item in text boxes.May be I am doing something wrong in controller with DropDownViewModel. I cannot find this class here. can u pls advise?

Comment: Got it, It is naming issue. I must give same name that is "ItemViewModel" for the editortemplate file also.

Comment: Some reason to use `IEnnumerable` in ViewModel instead of `List` for example ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Html Helper  DropDownList to build your drop down list but the model object should be inumerable of SelectionListItem.

```
//on controller
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Action", Value = "0"});
     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Drama", Value = "1" });
     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Comedy", Value = "2", Selected = true });
     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Science Fiction", Value = "3" });
     ViewBag.MovieType = items;

//on view

         @Html.DropDownList("MovieType")
```

If you do not want to build your Model object as SelectListItem, then you should use DropDownListFor

```
//you can use DropDownListFor as
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Text,m.Value)
```

Comment: Please look at question Update